Why assigned a jvm process id to jmap, but attach failed with no such process and show me another process id
$ jmap -heap 95320
Attaching to process ID 95320, please wait...
Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ..) failed for 600191: No such process
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ..) failed for 600191: No such process
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal$LinuxDebuggerLocalWorkerThread.execute(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:163)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.attach(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:278)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attachDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:671)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebuggerLinux(HotSpotAgent.java:611)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:337)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.go(HotSpotAgent.java:304)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attach(HotSpotAgent.java:140)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:185)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapSummary.main(HeapSummary.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:201)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:130)
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ..) failed for 600191: No such process
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.attach0(Native Method)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.access$100(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:62)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal$1AttachTask.doit(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:269)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal$LinuxDebuggerLocalWorkerThread.run(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:138)

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)

same problem when used jinfo
$ jinfo 95320
Attaching to process ID 95320, please wait...
Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ..) failed for 172336: No such process
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ..) failed for 172336: No such process

jstat was noraml


How did you check the PIDs - what does jps say about the process ids?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

jps says 95320, then used to execute "jmap -heap 95320"
